# Is there any way of using SenseRelate in Java?

Tags: java, nlp

I need to use WSD for my java project..i got to SenseRelate..but its all in Perl..is there any library available for using SenseRelate in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [IMS (It Makes Sense)](http://nlp.comp.nus.edu.sg/software), a Java WSD from NUS. Based on their [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/P/P10/P10-4014.pdf), their system was performing well as compared to state-of-the-art systems in different evaluations.

Answer (score 2):

First a caveat: WSD is a reasonably active area of research, so you probably shouldn't expect an easy answer with guaranteed accuracy. That said, you might consider LingPipe's implementation. See http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/wordSense/read-me.html.

I haven't used LingPipe's WSD system, but I've been pretty happy with the systems I have used. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: Where is it stated that LingPipe is AGPL-licensed? They announced they would adopt that license in 2009, but their website still lists the old non-open source license.

Comment: You're right. I was going from memory on what must have been an old LingPipe blog post. It looks like they never ended up switching to the AGPL. My apologies. Edited my original post to remove that erroneous statement.